# Does the translation rule of wavefunctions remain valid regardless of whether space is homogeneous or not?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, symmetry, group-theory

When we actively translate a system, we assume that its [wave function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function) *also* suffers a rigid translation without changing its shape. From which we get the standard result, relating the translated wavefunction with the untranslated one:

$$(1)\qquad\psi({\vec r},t)\to\psi^\prime({\vec r},t)=e^{-i {\vec p}\cdot\vec{a}/\hbar}\psi({\vec r},t) \ .$$

Of course, this is what would happen to any [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)) (not only wavefunctions) if we *can* move it *rigidly* by a vector $\vec{a}$ in space.

But can we perform such a rigid translation of wave functions? By rigid translation, I mean without disturbing its shape. In simpler terms, when we take the system and place it somewhere else, in general, we would expect (!) the wave function to change, because of the presence of external potentials.

Does the transformation rule $(1)$, given above, tacitly assume the space is homogeneous and does not hold when space is not homogeneous (inhomogeneous)?

Comment: It assumes that you move the whole "state preparation device"...

Comment: @TobiasFünke So if there is a source, providing an external potential, is it like moving the laboratory (system + potential supplying agency) as a whole? It is there we assume homogeneity of space. Did I get it?

Comment: This is what homogeneity of space means, no? If you perform the experiment at a different space point, which means you move the whole set-up (+ external fields, if possible; e.g. "translating" the effect of some gravitational field might be a problem.), "the physics" remains the same.

Comment: @TobiasFünke Thanks a lot :-) I was erroneously equating the homogeneity of space with the translational invariance of the system. Homogeneity of space is always true. But translational invariance requires that the Hamiltonian of the system commute with the momentum of the system, $[H,p]=0$. Therefore, eq. (1) is always true whether or not, $[H,p]=0$.

Comment: *Homogeneity of space is always true*-  as far as we know, yes. But technically it is an assumption. You can also write up an answer yourself, which might help other people with that question.

Comment: I'll try to do so. By the way, are all my remarks in response to your comments sound right to you? :-)