# What is the meaning of rotational symmetry in quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry

I often find in quantum mechanics text books that a system is rotationally invariant when the Hamiltonian $H$ commutes with rotational operator $R$. But not every Hamiltonian commutes with the rotational operator and so not every system is rotationally invariant.
But when we do experiments in the laboratory the energy of the system does not change, whether we rotate it or not. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: I should think that rotating a magnet in a strong external magnetic field in fact changes the energy of the system. (And the electron spin makes them act like magnets too, so this rotational assymmetry applies to electrons as well.) What exactly are the experiments you're talking about? Do you *expect* them to be non-rotationally invariant?

Comment: @HTNW you should rotate the magnetic field also not because it makes part of the hamiltonian too

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/775701/does-the-translation-rule-of-wavefunctions-remain-valid-regardless-of-whether-sp) discussion.